# Is the set W a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

> Let  $W = \{ (a,b): a, b \in \mathbb{R}, a + b = 1 \}$. For any $(a,b), (c,d) \in W$ and scalar r, define
> $$
> \begin{split}
> (a, b) + (c, d) &= (a+c-1, b+d)\\
> r \cdot (a, b) &= (ra - r +1, rb)
> \end{split}
> $$
> Prove or disprove $(W,+,\cdot)$ is a vector space.

**This is what I have:**

Let $u,v,w ∈ W , W \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.
I proved the 2nd axiom as
$$
u+v= (u_1 + v_1 - 1, u_2 + v_2)= ( u_1 + v_1 -1 , v_2 + u_2)= v+u.
$$
To prove that the set is a vector I just need to show that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication but I cant figure out the scalar multiplication part.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I'm having difficulties in figuring out how to prove axioms concerned with the scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $W$ is a vector space, where the identity element of addition is $(1,0)$ and additive inverse of $(a,b)$ is $(2-a,-b)$.

Moreover by considering the map $\Phi: (W,+,\cdot) \to (S,+,\cdot)$ given by
$$\Phi(a,b)=(1-a,b)$$
you may *translate* any operation over $W$ into an operation in $S=\{(x,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual operations $+$, $\cdot$.

Indeed, since $\Phi^{-1}=\Phi$ it follows that that for any $(a,b),(c,d)\in W$ and scalar $r$:
$$\Phi^{-1}(\Phi(a,b)+\Phi(c,d))=\Phi^{-1}((1-a,b)+(1-c,d))=
\Phi^{-1}(2-a-c,b+d)=(a+c-1,b+d)=(a,b)+(c,d)$$
and
$$\Phi^{-1}(r\cdot\Phi(a,b))=\Phi^{-1}(r\cdot (1-a,b))=\Phi^{-1}(r-ra,rb) = (ra - r +1, rb)=r \cdot (a, b).$$

Comment: We haven't covered that yet, or any maps

Comment: I didn't downvote anything, I can't even vote it says I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. I'm sorry, I just joined.

Comment: @kazbrekker You are right, sorry. You may try to verify each axiom keeping in mind that the identity element of addition is $(1,0)$ and additive inverse of $(a,b)$ is $(2-a,-b)$.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I completely looked over the part where it says a+b=1 before, so now I just proved that the set is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. Your answer seems right but it's kind of confusing me as I haven't actually learned about maps and translations. Thank you